# Flags and Signatures

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

A flag is an increasing sequence of subspaces of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$.

I assumed the dim $$V_i = d_i $$then we have

$${\displaystyle 0=d_{0}<d_{1}<d_{2}<\cdots <d_{n}=n,}$$

I don't know how to show the signatures will be $$(1,2,....,n)$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote, it is a strictly increasing sequence of natural numbers.

Exactly how many strictly increasing chains of $n+1$ integers between $0$ and $n$ (inclusive) do you believe there are?

This constraint is only made possible by the fact that subspaces can only be stacked $n+1$ deep in $\mathbb R^n$. If instead you had $k<n+1$ subspaces in that chain, there would be a chance for different behavior.

Comment: I believe just one, right? 1 to n